# How to calculate positions and randoms in scene. SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, math, sprite-kit

So here is a code :

```
static inline CGFloat randomInRange(CGFloat low, CGFloat high) {



CGFloat value = arc4random_uniform(UINT32_MAX) / (CGFloat)UINT32_MAX;
return value * (high - low) +low;
}

static const CGFloat HALO_LOW_ANGLE = 200.0 * M_PI / 180;
static const CGFloat HALO_HIGH_ANGLE = 340.0 * M_PI / 180;
static const CGFloat HALO_SPEED = 100.0;

-(void) spawnHalo {

SKSpriteNode *halo = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Halo"];
halo.position = CGPointMake(randomInRange(halo.size.width / 2, self.size.width - (halo.size.width / 2)), self.size.height + (halo.size.height / 2));
halo.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:16];
CGVector direction = radiansToVector(randomInRange(HALO_LOW_ANGLE, HALO_HIGH_ANGLE));
halo.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(direction.dx * HALO_SPEED, direction.dy * HALO_SPEED);
halo.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0;
halo.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0;
halo.physicsBody.friction = 0.0;
[self.mainLayer addChild:halo];
```

I get that first we wanted to get a random value between 0-1. but what i really don't understand is how to calculate the coordinates.

What if i want to spawn the sprite from anywhere, make it the right,left or the bottom of the scene. How do i actually calculate that ?

Comment: So you just want to spawn a node at a random position on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
CGPoint randomPosition = CGPointMake(arc4random() % (int)CGRectGetWidth(yourSceneInstance.frame),
                                     arc4random() % (int)CGRectGetHeight(yourSceneInstance.frame));
```

Comment: I actually want to understand the logic behind it, so i can write the code myself.talking about the code i provided.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are looking for, are you looking to know which would be the limits to generate your random position? From you code I don't see anything particularly wrong with what you are doing.

Comment: i know the code is correct, it's not mine i'm just a beginner in all this, so i don't really understand the code or the logic behind. What i'm looking for is some explanation for how to calculate where to spawn a sprite, and how to make it move in a random direction like the code above does.